# C# - On Mouse Drag Game Object follows Mouse on a single Axis. 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to create a 2d game and the game objects should follow the mouse on a single axis (the x axis), when the user drags the object.

1. Starting Point[image]
2. When i moved that shouldnt go up or down. [image]

Here's my code, the problem is, the game object is following the mouse everywhere i drag.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Draggable : MonoBehaviour, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler {

    public void OnBeginDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnBeginDrag");
    }

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnDrag");

        this.transform.position = eventData.position;
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("OnEndDrag");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently changing all axis(x,y,z) with `this.transform.position = eventData.position;`. Only change the x-axis. Use `eventData.position.x` only.

```
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log("OnDrag");
    Vector3 tempPos = this.transform.position;
    tempPos.x = eventData.position.x;
    this.transform.position = tempPos;
}
```

Comment: Vector3 huh i should explore more (y). can i ask another question? is it also possible to slow it down while dragging and have a limitation, cause im dragging it as a heavy object.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by slowing it down. Since this looks like different question, why not create a new question then provide the link here. I will take a look.

Comment: [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39083167/c-sharp-drag-and-then-drop-in-specified-area) 

Here it goes, Sir. (Master).