# C# - Drag and then Drop in specified area

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop, gameobject

I want my Item / GameObject, that to have its limit of draging. GameObject that have a place to stop, and wont able to use again. Droping Target/ Specified Place to Drop.

1. First Place of Bed
   [image]
2. The bed that have moved. In here, but the bed overlap the chair the should have bump.
   [image]
3. This is the bed that i want to end. The bed that can only move from its first place upto the side of the chair.
   [image]

Im still wondering if it is in some kind of "Vector" code.
Im newbie so im still exploring, and also, since its bed, i also want the user to drag the bed a little bit harder like a real person is pulling the big bed, if you know what i mean. If possible.

Code for dragging it. But limitless.

```
public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
{
    Debug.Log("OnDrag");
    Vector3 tempPos = this.transform.position;
    tempPos.x = eventData.position.x;
    this.transform.position = tempPos;
}
```

Comment: Not a lot of details to work with - to many people, your question is going to appear too broad. One approach: Track the current/target position of the bed. Target position passes through the chair (perhaps a raycast to accurately determine this) and is invalid? Then keep it in the current position. To make it "harder" to pull the bed, consider tracking mouse movement per frame and using that to move the bed, rather than directly placing the bed on the event position. Changing the ratio between mouse and bed movement will change how hard it is to move.

Comment: do you have colliders attached with your objects?

Comment: No colliders.
1) How can i drag the bed with only a little space, even there is no chair.